# Pretrained German BERT

Tags: nlp, bert

I'm looking for a (well) pretrained BERT Model in German to be adapted in a Keras/TF framework. Ideally with a minimal example on how to fine-tune the model on specific tasks, i.e. text classification!

Can anyone point me to some (open source) resources?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the huggingface website? They have a [list of NLP models](https://huggingface.co/models), including BERT models trained on the german language. See for example [this `bert-base-german-uncased` model](https://huggingface.co/dbmdz/bert-base-german-uncased) and [this `bert-base-german-cased` model](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-german-cased). The list also has some RoBERTa and some DistilBERT models if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Cheers, I‘ll have a closer look. I know about the deepset model. However, it is mostly trained on Wikipedia. So I wonder what alternatives are available.